# Can anyone help me figure out what my monthly take-home salary will be?

Tags: taxes, india, salary

I am a young software engineer in **India**, I was told that my **annual CTC** would be **`700000(annual CTC) + 50000(joining bonus)`**

**Basic Salary:** `23333` **per month**

**Flexible Benefit Plan**:`372932` **annually**

**Retirals**: `47000` **annually**

**Provident Fund**: `12%`

**Gratuity**: `4%`

They mentioned in offer letter that they will be offering restricted stock units of `142000` on grant date.

The details of **Flexible Benefit Plan** are:

[image]

Comment: Create a web page that can help one figure out Indian salaries based on income.

Comment: @PeteB. Every word of that was in English and I have no idea what the details of the question mean.  All of the lingo, and the concepts are completely different.  I thought it was bad between US and UK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not taking any of the options in the Flexible Benefit Plan, then everything is taxable. Check about "Retirals", the practise differs from organization to organization. Some pay it out annually and some only pay on completion of certain duration on exit.

So Deduct 47K from 7 lacs. Gross of around 653,000. Total tax for this around 53,000. After tax yearly around 600,000. Individual contribution to PF@ 12% of basic around 33,600. Net Yearly around 567,225. So net take home would be around 47,268.

You can easily take items 3,6,7,8 around 62,400. Thus you will save tax of around 13,000. So take home will increase 1,080.

Comment: My hr manager said it would be 45000+ , but did not mention the exact figure.